# How many cards can I access in R&D / HQ?

Tags: android-netrunner

My girlfriend and I started playing Netrunner this weekend, and after our first game taking roughly 4 days, we're now enjoying it!

I'm assuming that I'm just being thick here, but the manual never actually states how many cards you get to access in R&D / HQ. It says what happens "When accessing multiple cards", so in our first game we just assumed it was a choice about whether you wanted to carry on accessing cards or not.

However, when we ran across The Maker's Eye, this method of play suddenly seemed wrong. Am I to assume that I only get to access ONE card from R&D/HQ unless I have a card that allows me to access more?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a genuine question which falls within stackexchange criteria. If you downvote it, say why.

Comment: Not a problem with the question, but imagine if you could access as much as you wanted in R&D! Instant win if they're not running all their ice on it immediately or have a trap deck!

Comment: Downvotes are for "not much research effort", not for off-topic questions.  In this case, if you're getting downvotes, it is because people feel you should've seen it in the rules.  I wouldn't sweat it, I've gotten plenty of downvotes for missing obvious things.

Comment: @codeknight To post a question on stackexchange you need a computer and an internet access. These same resources can be used to access an electronic version of the rulebook. By searching that rulebook with "Ctrl-F" for the word "access" I have found the relevant rule in less than minute. You could find answer on your own, in a time comparable to the time you have spent on writing this question. Hence the downvote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's in the [official rulebook](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/android-netrunner-core-rules.pdf), under Access Phase in the section on Runs:

> • **R&D**: The Runner accesses the top card of R&D, and any upgrades
>   in its root...
>
> • **HQ**: The Runner accesses one random card from HQ and any upgrades
>   in its root...
>
> • **Archives**: The Runner accesses all cards in Archives and any
>   upgrades in its root...
>
> • **Remote Server**:  The Runner accesses all cards in the server.